# Import images from a folder with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, insert

Is there a jQuery script for importing images from a folder into an HTML page for use in a lightbox?

So in a folder, I will have:

image-1.jpg
image-2.jpg
image-3.jpg
etc.

and on the HTML page I will have:

```
<ul class="photoGallery">
  <li><img src="--insert here--"></li>
  <li><img src="--insert here--"></li>
  <li><img src="--insert here--"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to accomplish. Is this "folder" you're talking about on your server?

If so, you could make an Ajax call to a php script which then gives you all the images from said directory as a response. Then using JQuery you can simply generate the HTML based on that.

The thing is javascript is a client side language and your images are on a server.

In order to access server side information you need a server side language (like PHP in many cases). Then you write a server side script using that language which returns the path and name of the desired images. You then call said server side script in an AJAX call and generate the required HTML in JQuery.

Let's assume the directory you have your images in is called, very imaginatively, *images* and the php script is called *get_images.php*

Now in *get_images.php* you could do something like:

```
<?php

if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
{
    //redirect to Forbidden if page is called directly and not through AJAX
    header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
    exit;
}

$images = array(); 
foreach(glob("images/*") as $image) {
    $images[] = $image;
}
echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

And then in your JQuery script:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_images.php",             
    dataType: "json",            
});

request.done(function(response){                    
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
        $(".photoGallery").append('<li><img src="' + response[i] + '"></li>')
    }
});
```

Note that for this to work you would need to have the *images* directory, *get_images.php* and your *script.js* all in one directory. If this is not the case the url in the AJAX call and the path in PHP's `glob()` would have to be modified accordingly.

Comment: A bit more detail of what I'm after... Im building a website that has a photo gallery. The gallery has a simple jQuery lightbox plugin to make the images open in a popup screen etc. Normally all the images are listed on the page (in the html) but I want it to call from a folder on the server so that my client can just add images to a folder without having to edit the HTML every time they want to add/remove images. So I need a script that will call in the images from a folder (into a div) and add the class needed for the lightbox script.

Comment: So do you want all the images from the specified directory to be listed, or just the ones that are in the database entry?

Comment: I want the script to place all the images from the folder into the html

Comment: Answer updated with a code example of how you could go about it usong PHP and JQuery's `ajax()`.

Comment: I don't know much about PHP but I thought I could work it out. I failed. Would you mind please explaining how to set this up with a little more detail? So do I need to create a new (php) page with the php script in it and then link that page to the jQuery script? Do I need the <php? tags on the php page around the script?

Comment: Thanks for you time spent on this. I still couldn't get it to work but that's probably to do with me not knowing PHP and not your code. I think i'll have to read up and learn some PHP coding.